# Jenkins 2.190.2 Delivery pipeline view java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime

Tags: jenkins

After Jenkins upgrade to 2.190.2 and Java upgrade to openjdk version "1.8.0_232" version. my delivery pipeline view not working it showing `Error communicating to server!` error message.

in the Jenkins log file I see this exception saying joda datetime class not found. any idea why this throwing this error message?

```
# find . -name "*.jar" |grep joda
./plugins/jira/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
./plugins/pipeline-model-api/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar
./plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.5.jar
./plugins/blueocean-events/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
./plugins/blueocean-jwt/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
./plugins/blueocean-rest-impl/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
./plugins/handy-uri-templates-2-api/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.10.2.jar
./plugins/blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
./plugins/jira-steps/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.2.jar
./plugins/jira-steps/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-joda-2.4.0.jar
./tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle/lib/plugins/joda-time-2.8.2.jar
```

**Error Message**

```
2019-11-08 21:19:48.906+0000 [id=194]   WARNING o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler$Context#log: Error while serving https://.../view/test/api/json
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.api.Run.<init>(Run.java:57)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowApi.getRunsFor(WorkflowApi.java:37)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Task.getStage(Task.java:165)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Task.resolveTaskStatus(Task.java:179)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Task.resolveTask(Task.java:139)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Task.resolve(Task.java:126)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Stage.resolveStageNodes(Stage.java:141)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Stage.extractStages(Stage.java:124)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.model.Pipeline.resolve(Pipeline.java:135)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowPipelineView.resolvePipeline(WorkflowPipelineView.java:420)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowPipelineView.resolvePipelines(WorkflowPipelineView.java:413)
        at se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowPipelineView.getPipelines(WorkflowPipelineView.java:255)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.MethodProperty.getValue(MethodProperty.java:72)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.MethodProperty.getValue(MethodProperty.java:74)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.ExportInterceptor$1.getValue(ExportInterceptor.java:46)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to write pipelines:null
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.ExportInterceptor$1.getValue(ExportInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.Property.writeTo(Property.java:135)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.Model.writeNestedObjectTo(Model.java:223)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.export.Model.writeTo(Model.java:194)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.writeOne(ResponseImpl.java:287)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.serveExposedBean(ResponseImpl.java:278)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.serveExposedBean(ResponseImpl.java:234)
        at hudson.model.Api.doJson(Api.java:223)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:400)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:219)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)



---
2019-11-08 21:16:48.246+0000 [id=192]   INFO    h.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler#run: Accepted JNLP4-connect connection #13 from /192.168.37.90:49368
--> setting agent port for jnlp
2019-11-08 21:16:49.212+0000 [id=103]   SEVERE  h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler#uncaughtException: A thread (Thread-23/103) died unexpectedly due to an uncaught exception, this may leave your Jenkins in a bad way and is usually indicative of a bug in the code.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at tcp-slave-agent-port$_run_closure1.doCall(tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy:9)
        at tcp-slave-agent-port$_run_closure1.doCall(tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied `joda-time-2.10.2.jar` file to this location `$JENKINS_HOME/data/plugins/workflow-api/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.10.2.jar` and restarted the Jenkins. Its resolved the issue.

but not sure, this is the right way to fix the issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Delivery Pipeline plugin.

It uses Joda Time without declaring it as a direct dependency:

- https://github.com/Diabol/delivery-pipeline-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml
- https://github.com/Diabol/delivery-pipeline-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/se/diabol/jenkins/workflow/api/Run.java

They probably should use the `java.time.*` API to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's worked.

```sh
find $JENKINS_HOME -name *.jar | grep joda

/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-api/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar
/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.5.jar
```

Move plugin **joda-time-2.9.5.jar** to **$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/workflow-api/WEB-INF/lib/**

```sh
cp $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.5.jar $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/workflow-api/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.5.jar
```